# remove row from dataset

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, dataset, oledb

I would like to copy an excel data table into my `datagridview` but I want to start from a specific row where my table resides (row 9) (there are title, comments, etc.. before that that are not part of the table.)
I am using the following code but it doesn't delete the row from the `dataset`.

```
    MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
    MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection)

    DtSet = New System.Data.DataSet
    MyCommand.Fill(DtSet)
    DtSet.Tables(0).Rows(3).Delete()
    DtSet.Tables(0).Rows(3).AcceptChanges()


    dataGridArray(selectedTab).DataSource = DtSet.Tables(0)

    'MsgBox("number of Row(s)   -   " & DtSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count)

    MyConnection.Close()
```

after `delete()` and `acceptChanges`, I can still see the title.

Does anyone can see where am I wrong?
Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You don't want to [delete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.delete(v=vs.110).aspx) the row(in excel) but you want to [remove](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection.removeat(v=vs.110).aspx) it from the table.

So instead of:

```
DtSet.Tables(0).Rows(3).Delete()
```

use:

```
DtSet.Tables(0).Rows.RemoveAt(3)
```

But since you don't want to remove a single row as your code suggests but to remove all rows before the 9th row, use:

```
For i As Int32 = 1 To 8
    DtSet.Tables(0).Rows.RemoveAt(0)
Next
```

Comment: yes you are right I don't want to remove it. the result that I want is my data filled correctly in the dgv. But It seems not working, I got the same result. Thank you.

Comment: Ok I tried it. It does delete the rows. But now I got the "title, comments etc as header in my dgv. Even if I have row 3 and row 4 filled with text etc (which I don't want in my dgv)  I get things in row 3 as header in my dgv while row 4 is removed correctely.

Comment: @Nihilo: it's difficult to help without sample data. Have you used the debugger to see what's in the `DataTable`(you can inspect the whole table in the quick-watch window, use the loupe)? You have mentioned that you can remove everything before the 9th row, isn't that correct anymore??

Comment: Now I see what is happening by inspecting it. When I start to remove the rows, it has already set row 3 ( which I don't want) as column header. So text that are in row 3 in my orginal excel table ended up in the columns header in the dataTable. That is why is not removed in the loop u gave me. So it put the really first row with data as header but I want my row 9 as header where my table start. Anything that I can do? we are close, thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with the following code I don't know If it is the best elegant solution, but it works :

```
     MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;IMEX=1""")
    MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection)
    '  MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Net-informations.com")
    DtSet = New System.Data.DataSet
    MyCommand.Fill(DtSet)


    'find row with the second "item", there are 2. Its where my table starts
    For r = 0 To DtSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        If DtSet.Tables(0).Rows(r).Item(0).ToString = "Item" Then
            headerRowSearched = r
        End If
    Next

    'correct name header with the right one. 
    For c As Integer = 0 To DtSet.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
        DtSet.Tables(0).Columns(c).ColumnName = DtSet.Tables(0).Rows(headerRowSearched)(c)
    Next

    'remove all the junk rows up to my header
    For i As Int32 = 0 To headerRowSearched
        DtSet.Tables(0).Rows.RemoveAt(0)
    Next

    dataGridArray(selectedTab).DataSource = DtSet.Tables(0)

    MyConnection.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is just delete the column headers and replace them with data in row 9.